# Can't access a Google Apps Script deployed as a web app with an access token

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth

I'd like to understand a bit more how Apps Script web apps work when it comes to access them with a OAuth access token.

This is the Apps Script web app:

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
}

function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
}
```

It's deployed as: Me

Who has access to the app: See below

I use Postman to access the Apps Script web app. I call the web app URL (ending with `/exec`), and provide the header `Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`.

I generate access tokens using the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

- I'm signed-in as me: It works with every 'who has access to the app' permissions, which is what I expect.
- Signed-in as someone else within the domain: works only for 'anyone, even anonymous' permission, and only if the incoming request has no Authorization header. Otherwise I get a 403 Forbidden error.
  **I would expect it to work for the permissions below:**

  - 'anyone, even anonymous', even if the request has an Authorization header
  - 'anyone'
  - 'anyone within the domain'
- Signed-in as someone else outside the domain: works only for 'anyone, even anonymous' permission, and only if the incoming request has no Authorization header. Otherwise I get a 403 Forbidden error.
  **I would expect it to work for the permissions below:**

  - 'anyone, even anonymous', even if the request has an Authorization header
  - 'anyone'

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The scope used to generate the access token is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is directly related to your issue, can I ask you about the scopes including in the access token?

Comment: scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that the scope is not the reason of your issue.

Comment: Can you show us the error message when the status code of 403 occurs?

Comment: So for example with the app deployed with who-can-access set to 'anyone', and signed-in as a user outside the domain, the response is an html page. Title is 'You need permission', content is 'Want in? Ask for access, or switch to an account with permission. Learn more. You are signed in as xxxxx', and a button saying 'Request access'

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, as a test case, how about sharing publicly the script including ``doGet()`` and ``doPost``? After the script was shared publicly, can you try to access to Web Apps with the access token again? Of course, for the actual case, please don't share publicly. If this proposal works, please share the script only for each users.

Comment: Yes, in this case it works. You're right it looks like it relies on the script permissions, not on what you set up in the web app configuration. If I share the script with someone (read access), this person will be able to call the script too.
But I want the read and write permissions to be different than the run permission

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. You want to access to Web Apps under the condition of ``"Who has access to the app:": Anyone`` without sharing the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Before April 11, 2018, Web Apps had been able to be accessed (run the script) under the condition of ``"Who has access to the app:": Anyone`` without sharing the script. But after April 11, 2018, the specification was changed. In order to run the script of Web Apps, the script has been required to be shared to the user. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: If you want to make users access to Web Apps without sharing the script, for example, how about deploying Web Apps as ``"Who has access to the app:": Anyone, even anonymous`` and using the password with the query parameter and/or payload? In this case, the script is not required to be shared.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know. Thanks for your time! You can write an answer so I can validate it if you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted the workaround by including the sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this workaround?

#### Specification:

- When users access (run the script) to Web Apps which was deployed as `"Who has access to the app:": Anyone`, the script of Web Apps is required to be shared to the users. And also, the access token is required. This is the specification from April 11, 2018.

#### Goal:

- You want to access to Web Apps under the condition of `"Who has access to the app:": Anyone` without sharing the script.

Unfortunately, this can be directly achieved by the specification. So it is required to think of a workaround.

#### Workaround:

Under above situation, when you want to make users access to Web Apps without sharing the script, I would like to propose the following workaround.

1. Deploy Web Apps as `"Who has access to the app:": Anyone, even anonymous`.
2. When users access to Web Apps, users use a password with the query parameter and/or payload.

By above settings, you can make users access to Web Apps without sharing the script. In this case, the password is used instead of the access token.

#### Sample script: Web Apps side

In this sample, the password is used as the query parameter. This can be used like the use of API key.

```
function doPost(e) {
  if (e.parameter.password === "sample") {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error.");
}

function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.password === "sample") {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error.");
}
```

#### Sample curl: Client side

```
curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?password=sample"
```

#### Note:

- When it accesses to Web Apps deployed above condition using above curl sample, `Done.` is returned from `doGet()`. If the password is wrong, `Error.` is returned. By this, you can make users access to Web Apps without sharing the script.
- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please deploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)